# Java Convert byte array to PDF returns "undefined"

Tags: java, arrays, pdf

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a PDF document, but the the PDF file seems to be corrupted. And if open the file with a text reader the file just say "Undefined" I have searched through various stack topics but no luck. And the way i do it should work according to other topics. Below is my code. The code is executed trough a rest controller. Would really appreciate if someone could help me :).

//Controller

```
@ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value = "/orders/{orderCode}/receipt", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
  public void getOrderReceiptConroller(@PathVariable("orderCode") final String orderCode, final HttpServletResponse response)
  {
    response.setContentType(CoreConstants.MIME_TYPE_APPLICATION_PDF);
    final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(OrderFacade.getReceiptPdf(orderCode));
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try
    {
      outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
      IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    }
  }


// calls this code that returns the byteArray.
private byte[] getReceiptPdf()
    {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Edwresults edwResult = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(mockResponsePath), Edwresults.class);
            String response = edwResult.getResults().get(0).getData().get(0).getDigitalReceipt();
            byte[] byteData = response.getBytes();
            return byteData;
    }
```

Comment: You are ignoring all exceptions, are you sure that the stream actually gets copied? Are you sure `OrderFacade.getReceiptPdf` is actually returning the array you expect?

Comment: where JSON uses UTF-8 as default, FileReader uses the default platform encoding. The byteData should be checked (Start should be the bytes for PDF), maybe the PDF is stored as Base64 in the json.

Comment: I removed all try catches to make to code block smaller, Yes is should because the String "response" contains a mock static content, the only thing i not really sure if "response.getBytes()" does the job. but i have also tried to convert the String to a byteArray with  this method : public static byte[] readFully(InputStream stream) throws IOException
 {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
   baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  return baos.toByteArray(); }

Comment: Make sure that your getReceiptPdf method generates correct byte[] as a response. If you can generate a intermediary/temporary pdf file from that byte array and check if it is ok then the problem should be in IOUtils.copy method (maybe because encodings and etc.)

Comment: @Ahmet I tried to skip the IOUtils.copy method and used another one but no success..

Comment: Your code currently uses a mock response to start with. Thus, you know the PDF as it should be, Have you compared that original PDF with your result PDF? The result of the comparison should make clearer where to next look for the error.